# Software for monitoring internal software?

Tags: monitoring

Is there any good software for monitoring the health of a collection of related software?

Requirements are as follows:

- Web-based, deployable on standard Linux/BSD software.
- Configurable to support a variety of processes, scheduled at various intervals.
- Some sort of dashboard interface, for monitoring status, viewing errors, etc.

As an example, suppose we have a daily export that's scheduled to run at 6AM each morning. After the export completes, it would POST a status message, saying it had completed, passing in some sort of application key to identify the export. If that status message hadn't come in, by, say, 6:30AM, an e-mail might be sent, that application should go red on the dashboard, etc.

Applications should also be able to post error/warning messages.

Basically the goal is to be able to monitor all of our internal projects from one system, rather than a multitude of e-mails, log files, etc.

I suspect that I'll probably have to end up writing this from scratch, but I just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 4):

Nagios is everything you want. A little bit hard to configure correctly, but working great. Don't write your own software for that, Nagios already do that and is doing that very very good.

Related to posting messages on Nagios, you can use NSCA for remote or simple scripts for local.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Failsafe. It monitors server pings and webserver html request. Then it sends an alert and can run a script.
https://sites.google.com/site/bigsoftwarecreations/home/failsafe

Answer (score 1):

OpenNMS is cool too :) As @Sacx wrote: NagiOS is bit difficult in configuration.

Comment: True, nagios is a little bit hard to configure it, but is very very flexible.